# Is there an alternative to the Integrate tool that will not change one of the inputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, snapping

I have two polygon layers, and would like to snap the outlines of one of them (colored poly's) to the other (grey) without changing the grey in anyway (so Integrate seems out). It should only snap if the edge of the colored poly's is within a distance of the grey poly edges already, something like 200ft. There are several thousand of them that need snapped so it can't be a by hand method. Am I forgetting some tool that could do that since Integrate changes both inputs? I have ArcInfo 10.1 most if not all extensions and Xtools Pro.

Thanks.

[image: example]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a Standard or Advanced license, a simple approach is to use the [Snap (Editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000) tool.  The example shows the results of the snap using vertex snapping at a 20m distance.  Be advised this alters the input features but preserves the snap environment (in your case, the gray polygons).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it. I failed to realize that there was an actual snap tool outside the editor. Thanks