# Using Integrate tool to "snap" points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, snapping

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 for desktop.
I have two layers with points in them and I am trying to get the points of layer A to "snap" to the closest points of layer B. I am using the Integrate tool with a tolerance value that should match the greatest distance between the points of the two layers. The tool will run fine but the end result is that the points in both layer A and B are changed rather than just the points in layer A snapping to layer B. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange!  As a new user, please be user to [take the tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: The Snap Tool in Editing Tools might be a better choice than Integrate.

Comment: I think a picture showing what you start with and the result you are getting versus what you want would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting your xy tolerance, as [ArcGIS Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) indicates this situation will occur when the tolerance is too large:

> The feature class or layer with the lower rank will snap to the feature from the feature class or layer with the higher rank (with 1 being a higher rank than 2). Note that features in the feature class with a rank of 1 may move when a large x,y tolerance is used.

You may wish to try a different tool, such as [Snap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm). Warning: both Integrate and Snap will change your input dataset(s). Here's a similar question related to the Snap tool: [Is there an alternative to the Integrate tool that will not change one of the inputs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102701)